# openvpn server sometimes work on client with terminal, but not with networkmanager

Tags: vpn, linux-mint, openvpn, docker, centos-7

I am trying to get my openvpn server and client working. My server is a cent os 7 mashine and my client is mint sylvia.

I followed this tutorial on youtube with docker([link german](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8k7EK5LbgV4))
This are the docker steps:

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

systemctl start docker

systemctl status docker systemctl enable docker

docker volume create --name OVPN_DATA docker run -v OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_genconfig -u udp://vpn.servername.com - Hier IP oder Domain von eurem Server einfügen 

docker run -v OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm -it kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_initpki docker run -v OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -d -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN kylemanna/openvpn 

docker run -v OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm -it kylemanna/openvpn easyrsa build-client-full Desktop nopass 

docker run -v OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_getclient Desktop > Desktop.ovpn
```

**When I connect with the terminal(sudo openvpn --config file.ovpn) it sometimes work, but it takes like 5 minutes before a webpage is showing up. Here is my terminal output:**

```
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL(OpenSSL)] 

[LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]my_server_ip:1194
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1541', remote='link-mtu 1542'
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='comp-lzo'
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 WARNING: this cipher's block size is less than 128 bit (64 bit).  Consider using a --cipher with a larger block size.
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 WARNING: this cipher's block size is less than 128 bit (64 bit).  Consider using a --cipher with a larger block size.
Sun Jul 22 18:42:32 2018 [openvpn.domain.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]my_server_ip
Sun Jul 22 18:42:34 2018 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:1: block-outside-dns (2.3.10)
Sun Jul 22 18:42:34 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sun Jul 22 18:42:34 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun Jul 22 18:42:34 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sun Jul 22 18:42:34 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 192.168.255.6 peer 192.168.255.5
Sun Jul 22 18:42:34 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
Sun Jul 22 18:42:44 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:42:54 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:43:04 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:43:14 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:43:24 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:43:34 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:43:44 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:43:54 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:44:04 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:44:14 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:44:24 2018 write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Sun Jul 22 18:45:24 2018 [openvpn.domain.com] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Sun Jul 22 18:45:24 2018 /sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 local 192.168.255.6 peer 192.168.255.5
Sun Jul 22 18:45:24 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Sun Jul 22 18:45:26 2018 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Sun Jul 22 18:45:26 2018 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun Jul 22 18:45:26 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]my_server_ip
Sun Jul 22 18:45:27 2018 WARNING: this cipher's block size is less than 128 bit (64 bit).  Consider using a --cipher with a larger block size.
Sun Jul 22 18:45:27 2018 WARNING: this cipher's block size is less than 128 bit (64 bit).  Consider using a --cipher with a larger block size.
Sun Jul 22 18:45:27 2018 [openvpn.domain.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]my_server_ip:1194
Sun Jul 22 18:45:29 2018 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:1: block-outside-dns (2.3.10)
Sun Jul 22 18:45:29 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sun Jul 22 18:45:29 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun Jul 22 18:45:29 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sun Jul 22 18:45:29 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 192.168.255.6 peer 192.168.255.5
Sun Jul 22 18:45:29 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

And when I try to connect with the networkmanager I get this output in my log:

```
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278341.7389] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6" name="Notebook" pid=2096 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278341.7432] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 5119
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278341.7594] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278341.7797] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[5123] started
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278341.7797] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: Control Channel Authentication: using '/home/admin11/.cert/nm-openvpn/Notebook-tls-auth.pem' as a OpenVPN static key file
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]my_server_ip:1194
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1541', remote='link-mtu 1542'
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='comp-lzo'
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: WARNING: this cipher's block size is less than 128 bit (64 bit).  Consider using a --cipher with a larger block size.
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: WARNING: this cipher's block size is less than 128 bit (64 bit).  Consider using a --cipher with a larger block size.
Jul 22 18:52:21 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: [openvpn.domain.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]my_server_ip:1194
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:1: block-outside-dns (2.3.10)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --bus-name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn.Connection_6 --tun -- tun0 1500 1544 192.168.255.6 192.168.255.5 init
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4460] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4564] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4564] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4607] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4622] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4633] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data: VPN Gateway: 173.249.53.196
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4633] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data: Tunnel Device: "tun0"
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4633] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data: IPv4 configuration:
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4633] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal Gateway: 192.168.255.5
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4634] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal Address: 192.168.255.6
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4634] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal Prefix: 32
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4634] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 192.168.255.5
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4634] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4634] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Static Route: 192.168.255.1/32   Next Hop: 192.168.255.5
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4634] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Forbid Default Route: no
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4635] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 8.8.8.8
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4635] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 8.8.4.4
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4635] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data:   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4635] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: Data: No IPv6 configuration
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4636] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: chroot to '/var/lib/openvpn/chroot' and cd to '/' succeeded
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: GID set to nm-openvpn
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: UID set to nm-openvpn
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4685] vpn-connection[0x2560460,0627099f-d81d-4dd9-b919-792a1d03fda6,"Notebook",8:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) complete
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4691] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4741] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4743] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4750] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dnsmasq[1610]: vorgelagerte Server von DBus gesetzt
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dnsmasq[1610]: Benutze Namensserver 8.8.8.8#53(via tun0)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dnsmasq[1610]: Benutze Namensserver 8.8.8.8#53 für Domain 6.255.168.192.in-addr.arpa
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dnsmasq[1610]: Benutze Namensserver 8.8.8.8#53 für Domain 1.255.168.192.in-addr.arpa
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dnsmasq[1610]: Benutze Namensserver 8.8.4.4#53 für Domain 6.255.168.192.in-addr.arpa
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dnsmasq[1610]: Benutze Namensserver 8.8.4.4#53 für Domain 1.255.168.192.in-addr.arpa
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dnsmasq[1610]: Benutze Namensserver 8.8.4.4#53(via tun0)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dnsmasq[1610]: Benutze Namensserver 192.168.178.1#53(via enp5s0f1)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dbus[1213]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4861] keyfile: add connection in-memory (92e3b7db-471b-410a-815c-1e2d1446a952,"tun0")
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4869] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4882] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (92e3b7db-471b-410a-815c-1e2d1446a952)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4892] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4897] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4900] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4903] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4910] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4914] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4934] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4936] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4937] policy: set 'tun0' (tun0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G NetworkManager[1225]: <info>  [1532278344.4938] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G dbus[1213]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-up' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-up' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jul 22 18:52:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jul 22 18:52:26 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Listen normally on 14 tun0 192.168.255.6:123
Jul 22 18:52:26 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Listen normally on 15 tun0 [fe80::72a0:ae4f:6a61:37f9%8]:123
Jul 22 18:52:26 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Jul 22 18:52:29 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 94.16.114.254
Jul 22 18:52:29 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jul 22 18:52:29 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpdate[5201]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting
Jul 22 18:52:32 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 94.130.183.105
Jul 22 18:52:34 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Jul 22 18:52:34 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 85.236.36.4
Jul 22 18:52:42 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 2001:67c:1560:8003::c8
Jul 22 18:52:44 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Jul 22 18:53:14 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: message repeated 3 times: [ write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)]
Jul 22 18:53:20 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 178.63.9.110
Jul 22 18:53:24 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Jul 22 18:53:33 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 178.63.9.110
Jul 22 18:53:34 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Jul 22 18:53:35 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: message repeated 4 times: [ write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)]
Jul 22 18:53:36 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 185.120.22.12
Jul 22 18:53:36 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Jul 22 18:53:40 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 37.120.191.245
Jul 22 18:53:46 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Jul 22 18:53:51 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G ntpd[1319]: Soliciting pool server 2001:67c:1560:8003::c7
Jul 22 18:53:52 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G kernel: [ 2086.906093] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0f1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:5c:49:79:ce:17:7b:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=43670 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 18:53:56 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
Jul 22 18:54:16 notebook-Aspire-V5-573G nm-openvpn[5123]: message repeated 2 times: [ write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)]
```

Hope, someone can help me, I am a bit lost. Thanks!!